# Is this a bug in minitest, sprockets-rails, or ruby-2?

Tags: sprockets, testunit, minitest, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I wanted to patch a bug in sprockets-rails, but when I ran the test suite (using ruby-2.0.0-p0 as well as ruby-head), I got the following error:

```
/Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:707:in `block in _prepare_run': undefined method `size' for #<ParallelEach:0x007f823aa55e88> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:707:in `each'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:707:in `inject'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:707:in `_prepare_run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:648:in `_run_suites'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails-dev/gems/minitest-4.7.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:861:in `_run_anything'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails-dev/gems/minitest-4.7.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1068:in `run_tests'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails-dev/gems/minitest-4.7.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1055:in `block in _run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails-dev/gems/minitest-4.7.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1054:in `each'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails-dev/gems/minitest-4.7.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1054:in `_run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails-dev/gems/minitest-4.7.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1042:in `run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:774:in `run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:834:in `run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:838:in `run'
    from /Users/btaitelb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/testrb:7:in `<main>'
```

I'm not clear on the relationship between Test::Unit and MiniTest, especially since I see test/unit.rb referencing MiniTest::Unit

I can patch this issue in a couple ways, but I'm not sure which project is to blame (e.g. where I should submit the patch):

1. In test/unit.rb in ruby, I can replace the call to `size` with a call to `count`, but this only seems appropriate if `Test::Unit` expects a `ParallelEach` being part of the test suite
2. In minitest, I can alias `count` to `size`, which makes sense if minitest is responsible for sending `ParallelEach` objects to `Test::Unit`

Are either of these appropriate, or is there something else going on here (like a naming conflict)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in minitest, that has since been fixed: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/275